# Best Practices to insert to two tables in YII

Tags: postgresql, yii

Iam developing a website in Yii with POSTGRES.

In that there have 2 tables `table1, table2`. When i inserting a row into table1 i just need to the same row in table2.

How can i do this?

If there is any best practices for that......

Or Stored Procedure will be suitable here?

Iam new in this ..

This is insert code for table1:

```
 $connection = Yii::app() -> db;
    $sql = 'INSERT query here';
    $command = $connection -> createCommand($sql);
    $command -> execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two way 
1. Either you use a `trigger` in table1 that after insert insert the data into table 2
or
2.You write a store `procedure or function` that will take the insertion value as input and insert the data in both of the tables.

This is an example of trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_data_ins_TRIGGER()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    insert into table2(table_fields) values(NEW.FIELD1,NEW.FIELD2);
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_fn_data_ins_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_data_ins_TRIGGER();
```

Comment: A `DO ALSO` rule will also work here. Kichu, I suggest reading the PostgreSQL documentation on triggers.